# DB Design question - general relation table is practical?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have models `X` and `Y` that can be liked, currently I have `x_likes` and `y_likes` join tables

```python
class XLike(Base):
    __tablename__ = "x_likes"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    x_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("x.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

Is this the best way to duplicate this relation table per entity I want to have the ability to like in my app or is there an alternative?

I thought about a table that will have general use, it receives `user_id`, `entity_id`, and `entity_table`, my questions are, is it a good practice? if so, how to implement it, if not, are there any alternatives to this problem?

Comment: This is generally the better way, because you can declare a proper foreign key relationship. If there's a single `Like` table, the foreign key can't be declared.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to duplicate the foreign keys in a single table with an additional type column:

```py
# You could use an enum here as well.
like_types = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 1
}

class Like(Base):
    __tablename__ = "likes"
    # To maintain integrity since foreignkeys can be NULL we must check that at least one is set.  This also confirms the fk that is set matches the type.
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('(type = 0 AND x_id IS NOT NULL) OR (type = 1 AND y_id IS NOT NULL)'),
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    type = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    
    x_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("x.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
    y_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("y.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
    x = relationship("X")
    y = relationship("Y")
    #...
```

This makes displaying a list of what a user has liked easier but will be harder to change as you add more "likable" things.  Ie. You will need to drop the check constraint and rebuild it as well as add another column to the table.  I'm not sure about performance that would all depend on the situation.

```py
# Example query to select likes and preload their relationsthips.
q = select(Like).options(joinedload(Like.x), selectinload(Like.y)).order_by(Like.created_on.desc()).limit(20)
```

The generic `entity_table` solution will require a lot of manual configuration in SQLAlchemy and also will most likely be rather slow.